# Azure Data Explorer Command dynamic parameter error

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-explorer, adx

I have added "Azure Data Explorer Command" in ADF pipeline,  but it is not accepting dynamic parameters inside command expression.

ex:  Step 1: added Azure Data Explorer Command

[image]

Step 2:  Added two parameters
[image]

Step 3: Added dynamic expression in command window

[image]

Step 4:  Added Kusto function with parameters

```
.append rfi_ret_qhour_agg <| RFIRetFactAggFunction(@pipeline().parameters.windowStart),@pipeline().parameters.windowEnd)
```

Not sure why but above expression with dynamic parameters not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you need to call a ADX function and pass the parameters into it. I would achieve this by the following using @concat.

```
@concat('rfi_ret_qhour_agg <| RFIRetFactAggFunction(',pipeline().parameters.windowEnd,pipeline().parameters.windowStart,')')
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try to wrap the parameters with curly brackets:

`.append rfi_ret_qhour_agg <| RFIRetFactAggFunction(@{pipeline().parameters.windowStart}),@{pipeline().parameters.windowEnd})`